# Titan Black 6GB for US$ 270 - good deal for DL?

Tags: deep-learning

I want to upgrade my GTX 650ti 1GB for something better suited for deep learning. I was offered a Titan Black 6 GB for US 270. I know there are several better cards today, but my budget limit is US$ 300.
Any recommendations?

Gonzalo

Comment: Ok, I went for the Titan Black...